# Host name incorrect for logstash monitoring in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I was able to configure logstash 6.7.1 to enable monitoring and it's successfully showing up in Kibana.
However the host name is incorrect, it defaults to 127.0.0.1:9600 and 127.0.0.1:9601 for all 3 nodes in my cluster. Am I missing something?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the defaul behavior, `127.0.0.1` is the default value for the setting `http.host` in the `logstash.yml` file.

The `http.host` variable is the metrics REST endpoint, used for get the monitoring metrics, if you do not specify an ip address, it will bind to the localhost ip, which is `127.0.0.1`.

If you want it to show another ip address present in the server, you will need to set this variable to that ip address.